# Rails get associations on condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, relational-database

I have a problem - I do not know how to get associated records only if condition is met.

I have Posts model and Comments, Post `has_many :comments`, Comment `belongs_to :post`.

Now, I want to retrieve All of the Posts, but only with specific comments (lets say with user_id = 1).
How can I achieve that?
Query like

`Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.user_id = ?", "1")` will retrieve only some Posts, I want all of them, but only with comments with user_id equal to 1.

I guess I should use LEFT JOIN of some sort, maybe something like

`posts.joins("LEFT JOIN comments ON posts.id comments.post_id")`

but I am not sure how to put condition restricting right table results.

Comment: `will retrieve only some Posts` what does it mean? you don't get any results that you expected to get?

Comment: If you want the post which has comments by user with id 1, the above query should work. Unless you expected some other response. Can you tell us the response you got.

Comment: As I said, I want ALL OF THE POSTS, but do not load all of the posts comments, just comments that meet the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved as below

```
Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.user_id = ?", "1").references(:comments)
```

For more information go [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes)

Comment: well - I do not get posts that do not have any comments - any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Can you try this, I am not sure this works or not "Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.user_id = ? or comments.id is null", "1").references(:comments)"

Comment: Well, it was bad example on my part (I simplified given example, in reality where clause contained other value than foreign key). Translating here I used `includes(:comments).where('comments.user_id IS NULL OR (comments.message = ?', message).references(:comments)`. Thanks to that I get all the Posts (even these without commetns), with comments limited to ones containing specified message.

Comment: Great finally found the solution.